# Right authentication for B2B application - JWT, OAuth etc

Tags: security, authentication, firebase, oauth, jwt

I read articles on choosing the right authentication mechanism and I understand that JWT just defines a token while OAuth is a full framework that can use JWT. There are also other frameworks (Firebase?) and token-standards.

Now for my specific use-case I have a single-page-, microservice app with Angular2 that will run the whole day in the browser without any refreshing, in a rather old B2B environment (2GB ram, IE11). So social logins are not needed and a lightweight solution is preferable. Can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This questionary could help

Are you using a forms based web or a SPA?

- Forms: Use server sessions
- SPA: Use authentication tokens (JWT or opaque)

Using authentication tokens, do you want to avoid storing session data at server side?

- Yes: Use JWT
- It does not matter: Use opaque tokens

The client needs to verify token or extract token claims?

- Yes: Use JWT signed with RSA
- No: Use JWT with HMAC or opaque tokens

Do you have an API for third party?

- Yes: Use OAuth2 or OpenIDConnect issuing authentication tokens after succesful user login
- No: Nothing extra

Do you want to manage user passwords?

- Yes: Make your own registration and login forms
- No: Integrate social logins (they use oauth/OIDC)